# Avoid @ModelAttribute("attr") loading for every URL

Tags: java, spring, modelattribute

I have a drop down in jsp where am populating data from database for that am using @modelAttribute. But whenever the url hits before that url execution model attribute code runs and hits database unwantedly.... Is der any way to avoid this....
my code is

```
@ModelAttribute("courseList")
    public Map<String, String> gerCourseNameList(HttpSession session,
        HttpServletRequest httpSevletRequest, HttpServletResponse response,
        ModelMap model) throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> map = null;

 ------ My code here------

}
```

My log file here

```
 [DEBUG] SessionFilter| Url :http://localhost:8080/EnKalviV1/studentallocation.htm
 [06 May 2015 15:01:11] [Inst Id: INS | Branch Id: BR001 | User Id: bradm1 | Session Id: 97910CBDA9FF68175302717842E9923F]
 [DEBUG] LoggingAspect| Class Name :com.jaw.student.controller.StudentAllocationController,Calling gerCourseNameList() method.
 [06 May 2015 15:01:11] [Inst Id: INS | Branch Id: BR001 | User Id: bradm1 | Session Id: 97910CBDA9FF68175302717842E9923F]
```

Even for ajax call in that controller also this code is running...

How to avoid this....

Comment: http://localhost:8080/EnKalviV1/studentallocation.htm this url must be mapped to a method? Please post the remaining class code

Answer (score 0):

This method is run whenever a request is received that does not contain a model attribute of that name.

Add an annotation to your controller class

```
@SessionAttributes ({"courseList"})
```

This will cause the model attribute to be added to the session and then it will be added back to the model on each request, prior to the check that would otherwise result in the method being executed.